# Is there a way to dynamically href to an unknown file name?

Tags: html, href

I have a link to a pdf file on my website and every few months the file is updated and the name changed based on when it was created.  Is there a way in which I can have a dynamically changing href that does something like linking to the first file in a directory so that all I have to do is drop the new file into a folder and not have to change the href in the webpage code?

Comment: Point to an url where the server side script redirects you to the latest?

Comment: You cannot do that in HTML, it requires some logic on the server.